# Android signed certificate error using same certificate for update

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to update a current app on Google Play. I am using a .keystore file that I am certain is the same one as the previous version and I am certain the password is correct. I have updated the versionCode and versionName in the manifest.xml and read through all of the android documentation for submitting an update. I just used this same .keystore to update another app and it worked fine.When I try to upload the new .apk file I get the following error:

**Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):**

**[ SHA1: CB:17:93:81:FA:07:6E:B7:4C:83:EA:64:79:85:44:3B:7D:08:71:6E ]**

**and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):**

**[ SHA1: ED:79:37:8A:77:3A:6E:82:8A:60:55:95:99:0E:56:60:CB:5B:3C:EF,**

**SHA1: CB:17:93:81:FA:07:6E:B7:4C:83:EA:64:79:85:44:3B:7D:08:71:6E ]**

as you can see, the 2nd (new) certificate's 2nd SHA1 argument is identical as the 1st certificates. But, for some reason the 2nd certificate has 2 SHA1: arguments.  Does anyone know why it would have 2? I cant find any information on this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @rbertsch8- Hey I am having same problem...did get u any solution..?? I am having one  wrong SHA1 certificate instead of two !!

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid - No unfortunately. We had to unpublish the old version and republish it with a new name. I emailed google several times and all they gave me was some automated response BS, so I wouldn't waste your time with that. Times like this when I realize how much better Apple's App Store support is despite their 30% cut and strictness. We potentially lost several thousand users by updating versions.

Comment: @rbertsch8-Thanks for guidance..much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

I only had a quick look but according to this [Can we load multiple Certificates & Keys in a Key Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370745/can-we-load-multiple-certificates-keys-in-a-key-store) it is possible to have more than one key, are you sure you used the correct alias?