# How is the alias name used in Java KeyStore class?

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate

Class KeyStore has a method called setCertificateEntry(alias, certificate). Most client examples I see use "ca" as the alias name. Is the server asking for "ca" automatically during the client-server handshake? What really would happen if I use "abc" instead of "ca?" Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The alias is really just a name that is local to the keystore you are using. It is what identifies the entry in the keystore, so you can't re-use it for two entries, but it can be whatever you like (although I must admit I have never tried with non-ASCII characters, and the official truststore only uses lower case letters or numbers).

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) also says:

> Whether aliases are case sensitive is implementation dependent. In order to avoid problems, it is recommended not to use aliases in a KeyStore that only differ in case.

Some keystore implementations and formats might have more constraints or use that name differently. For example, the [`WINDOWS-ROOT`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/security-137537.html) keystore (which is a front-end for the Windows native store) uses Windows's "friendly name" as the alias, which is unfortunately not unique in the Windows certificate store, so some certificates from the native store may be hidden and not usable (it's a map from alias to entry, loading a new entry with the same name replaces the other one). However, this shouldn't be a concern on Android, of course.

If you're building a keystore that you'll use as a truststore, which is likely to contain a number of CAs, calling one "`ca`" would make it difficult to identify them later on. (This is mostly an administrative problem to be able to find manually which cert is where.)

If you look at the default truststore, you'll get aliases with names the resemble the Subject DN of these CA certificates, for example "`verisignclass1g2ca`".

Having an identifier you can remember is generally more important for keystores that are used as keystores (as opposed to truststores) and which contain multiple private key entries, since this can help you configure your application to use a particular certificate to identify itself.