# What is the purpose of aliases in x509 certificate?

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, x509

I am currently working on a PKI and I was wondering if aliases have some other purpose except providing "a friendly name" ([Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27515_01/common/tutorials/general_certificates.html))?

So far I have implemented validation of certificate chains by having unique alias for every chain. So if a certificate issuer is root, then a user must specify subjects' alias, and if not root, subjects' alias is "inherited" from issuer.

What is the correct way of dealing with aliases?
Thanks

Comment: Alias is simply a friendly name for entry in keystore and help you identify (distinguish) certificates with same subject, but with different purposes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27072660/3997611