# How does Spring Boot decide which certificate will be used from keystore case of multiple domains?

Tags: java, ssl, dns, keystore

We have case where we have to change our server URL, but one old deprecated service does not let us change our URL there so we decided to have 2 URL-s running at the same time behind the same server and for new services we would provide a new URL.

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=/ourkeystore
server.ssl.key-store-password=@keystore.key@
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2
server.ssl.trust-store=ourtruststore
```

If we have 2 certificates in keystore, then what I have to do for server to know which one to use based on the URL?

Answer (score 1):

in order to select desired certificate you can specify certificate alias:

```
server.ssl.key-alias
```

more details about multiple certificates in one keystore is provided in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6371359/10436325).