# QuickFIX/J with multiple certificates

Tags: ssl, failover, quickfixj

With QuickFixJ connection type as Initiator, I need to configure failover.

The documentation at https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/configuration.html#Initiator allows us to configure alternate `SocketConnectHost` and `SocketConnectPort` for failover.

However I have requirement from the acceptor that for different `SocketConnectHost`, I need to use different SSL certificate.

Does QuickFixJ support this? Or I have to manually overwrite the certificate while it is attempting to connect to different acceptor?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with keystore or SSL specialities, but shouldn't you be able to put several certificates into one single keystore and supply this keystore in the config?

Also see [Can we load multiple Certificates & Keys in a Key Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6370745/4962355)